# Retrieve JSON object after jQuery get finish

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, response

I'm trying to retrieve JSON object using jQuery get, and the Object I retrieve I want to embed in innerHTML. The following code is how i construct my JSON

getListOfActivity.jsp

```
<%  
        String urusStr = request.getParameter("ukid");
        int urusId = Integer.parseInt(urusStr);

        lkpPdkCommon[] activity = getListOfActivity(urusId);
        if(activity!=null){
            out.println("{PartList:");
                out.println("[");
                    for(int x=0;x<2;x++){// the lkpPdkCommon[] return from getListOfActivity(urusId) huge so I limit the array to 2         
                        out.println("{");
                            out.println("ActivityID:\""+activity[x].getID()+"\",Description:\""+activity[x].getDescription()+"\"");
                        out.println("}");
                        if((x+1)!=2){
                            out.println(",");
                        }
                    }
                out.println("]");
            out.println("}");   

            response.setContentType("application/json");

    %>
```

and below code is my jQuery/jscript

```
    var ukid = document.getElementById("ukid").value
    var aktivityId = row.insertCell(1);
    var description = row.insertCell(2);
    var JSONObject;         
    var $ac = jQuery.noConflict();
    $ac.get("../../getListOfActivity.jsp",{ukid:ukid}, function(data){  
        JSONObject = data   

//for testing purposes I do not iterate through the JSON Object

        aktivityId.innerHTML = JSONObject.PartList[0].ActivityID
        description.innerHTML = JSONObject.PartList[0].Description
    });
```

The following code didn't return any error, but it seems doesn't work. This is the JSON Object I check using firebug

[image: JSON Object]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Jquery getJSON.

I think this would help you.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved after I modified the following line in jsp

```
out.println("{PartList:");
```

to

```
out.println("{\"PartList\":");
```

and

```
    out.println("ActivityID:\""+activity[x].getID()+
"\",Description:\""+activity[x].getDescription()+"\"");
```

to

```
    out.println("\"ActivityID\":\""+activity[x].getID()+
"\",\"Description\":\""+activity[x].getDescription()+"\"");
```

The original JSON object send by response header before I do the modification are like below:

```
{PartList:
        [
            {ActivityID:"8638",Description:"GERMS"},
            {ActivityID:"8639",Description:"GOVERNMENT CERTIFY PROGRAMMES"}
        ]
}
```

and after the modification

```
{"PartList":
        [
             {"ActivityID":"8638","Description":"GERMS"},
             {"ActivityID":"8639","Description":"GOVERNMENT CERTIFY PROGRAMMES"}
        ]
}
```